# Laravel csrf_field() Is Blank

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am learning about **Packages** in **Laravel 5.4** and ultimately I will upload them to github.

This is my directory structure :

```
laravel
-vendor
--student
---myPackage
----src
-----Views
------myView.blade.php
```

the `myView.blade.php` has a form in it, and a `{{csrf_field()}}` function call, but when I inspect the output in the browser, the `value attribute` of the hidden input `<input name="_token" value="" type="hidden">` is empty.

**How do I make this work ?**

**SOLUTION**

> Apparantly, I needed to make sure that the web middleware is in use
>   for my routes, so I changed `Route::get('/Register/{group}',
>   'Student\myPackage\Http\User@create');` to
>   `Route::get('/Register/{group}',
>   'Student\myPackage\Http\User@create')->middleware('web');`

Route:

```
Route::get('/Register/{group}', 'Student\myPackage\Http\User@create');
Route::post('/Register/{group}', 'Student\myPackage\Http\User@store');
```

Controller:

```
public function create($group){
    return view('StudentUser::app', ['group' => $group]);
}

public function store($group)
{
    dd(request()->all());
}
```

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/Register/{{$group}}">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="ap-about" class="tab-pane active">
            {!! csrf_token() !!}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" required autofocus>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Next
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ap-personal" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address" class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" name="personal[]" value="" required autofocus>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url" class="col-md-4 control-label">url</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="url" type="text" class="form-control" name="personal[]" value="" required autofocus>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you add your form please ?

Comment: Do you define route in web.php to access myView?

Comment: @Mohammadb Yes, I can access myView, and can access all the other request fields too.

Comment: please put route or controller code that you return myView

Comment: @Mohammadb Done

Comment: you can't use `csrf_token ` without any tag you need to define hidden input tag
`<input name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" type="hidden">`

Comment: @MortaddaJafar No, it's still not working.

Comment: is works inside app namespace controller?

Comment: @MortaddaJafar Yes it is working in the app namespace. Just not in the package

Comment: see here this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475093/laravel-5-2-csrf-token-doesnt-work

Comment: @SagarGautam Thanks. Adding web middleware to the route did the trick.

Comment: @MortaddaJafar in 5.4 you don't need to put the input tag for the csrf to work. `{{ csrf_field() }}` this itself output the whole input tag along the token value.

Comment: @StudentX Congrats bro

Comment: @StudentX yes , but i said  `csrf_token`  not `{{ csrf_field() }}`   look your form code!

Comment: @MortaddaJafar Oops, my bad :P